# combining two JSON {key1:value1 , key2:value2} to single key (i e {key3:value1,value2}) Python

Tags: python, json

I want to combine longitude and latitude to 
{latlon: '40.33333,-79.34343'}

the entire JSON is in variable data = jsonData

I want to remove original key-value pair

```
{
  'locale': 'en_US',
  'timezone': '-7',
  'id': '13',
  'agerangemin': '21',
  'verified': 'true',
  'coverimageurl': 'scontent.xx.fbcdn/t31.0-0/p480x480/13063482_1183967848280764_1411489384515766669_o.jpg',
  'tagline': 'Veggien',
  'lastupdated': '1462341401',
  'fbupdated_time': '2016-03-30T00:38:48+0000',
  'lname': 'Kulkarni',
  'fname': 'Nikhil',
  'email': 'nikhilhk.usa@gmail.com',
  'latitude': '40.333333',
  'longitude': '-79.34343',
  'displayname': 'Nikhil Kulkarni',
  'fbprofileid': '1121344884543061',
  'profileimageurl': 'scontent.xx.fbcdn/hprofile-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/10423743_952350738109144_964810479230145631_n.jpg?oh=71f7e953dbbf8e2f1d9f22418f7888b2&oe=579F4A36',
  'link': 'facebook/app_scoped_user_id/1121344884543061/',
  'diet': 'Vegetarian',
  'dietsinceyear': '1966',
  'gender': 'M',
  'vegstory': '',
  'shortdescription': 'Just like that',
  'categoryids': '',
  'reasonforveg': 'Religious'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> json_data['latlon'] = ','.join(json_data[k] for k in ('latitude', 'longitude'))
>>> json_data['latlon']
'40.333333,-79.34343'
```

Note that this will preserve the original key-value pair.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to remove the original key-value pair use [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method:

```
>>> json_data['latlon'] = ','.join(json_data.pop(k) for k in ('latitude', 'longitude'))
>>> json_data['latlon']
'40.333333,-79.34343'
```

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of downvotes if there are no relevant comments. If the answer is not good or needs improvement a comment would really help everyone.

Comment: If your answer was just, there was no reason to edit it, seems fair?

Comment: Well, the OP edited the question about `removing the original key-pair` after I answered and I only looked at it just now. And, that's why the required update. If the downvoter would have commented the reason as well, I would have appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['latlong'] = data['latitude'] + ',' + data['longitude']
del data['latitude']
del data['longitude']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line.

```
>>> dic = {'latitude': '40.333333', 'longitude': '-79.34343'}
>>>
>>> dic['latlon'] = "{0},{1}".format(dic.pop('latitude'),dic.pop('longitude'))
>>> dic
{'latlon': '40.333333,-79.34343'}
```

To understand how `dic.pop()` work, see [this.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)